# WebView overlaps toolbar

Tags: android, webview, android-toolbar

I'm creating an application and I encountered some problem with my toolbar and webview. My webview overlaps my toolbar on top. How can I fix this?

Here is my sample screenshot:

activity_main:
[image: activity_main]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ececec"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_top" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_bot" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour">

    <!--STARTWEBVIEW -->
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    <!--ENDWEBVIEW-->

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

can you paste the code of toolbar_top and toolbar_bot

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ececec"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#663300"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
         />

<!--STARTWEBVIEW -->
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<!--ENDWEBVIEW-->

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#663300"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```